# Telerik MVC Ajax Grid - Adding ViewModel to other ViewModel before save to DB

Tags: telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Let's say i have 2 Models:

Customer (ID,Name) <[0..1 - *]> Invoice (ID,Name,Value).

Now, the Route /Customer/Create allows me to Create a new Customer (one text box for the Name) and below the TelerikGrid, which adds Invoices to the Customer.

My solutions was:

1. creating a Customer (with default name e.g. "-")
2. save to db
3. read the CustomerId
4. add the invoices to this CustomerId
5. Save the Customer again

my goal:

/Customer/Create/ -> creates a new CustomerViewModel-Object, displays the view with the grid, which is bound to the InvoiceViewModel (Property of CustomerViewModel)

```
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
            .Ajax()
            .Insert("InsertInvoice", "Customer")
```

the ajax-Method should act like:

```
private CustomerViewModel myCustomerViewModel;

public ActionResult Create()
{
     this.myCustomerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel();
     this.myCustomerViewModel = new List<InvoiceViewModel>();

     return View(this.myCustomerViewModel);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult InsertInvoice(InvoiceViewModel newInvoice)
{
     this.myCustomerViewModel.Invoices.Add(newInvoice)
     return View(new GridModel(this.myCustomerViewModel.Invoices));
}
```

finally, when i click the "Create" Button for creating a new Customer, it should save it to DB.

now i'm stucking because when i call the "InsertInvoice"-Method, myCustomerViewModel is NULL.

Idea?

best regards,
dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved, but i don't know if it's "clean",nevertheless:

old:

```
private CustomerViewModel myCustomerViewModel;
```

now:

```
public CustomerViewModel CurrentCustomer
{
    get
    {
        return (CustomerViewModel )Session["CurrentCustomer"];
    }
    set
    {
        Session["CurrentCustomer"] = value;
    }
}
```